# C#: Strongly type heterogenous container accept nullable

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to adapt the following code, to also acceptable nullable type. Consider this:

```
public sealed class JsonDictionary
{
    private readonly IDictionary<string, object> _data;

    public static readonly Key<int> Foo = new Key<int> { Name = "FOO" };
    public static readonly Key<double> Bar = new Key<double> { Name = "BAR" };
    public static readonly Key<List<double>> Vec = new Key<List<double>> { Name = "VEC" };

    public JsonDictionary()
    {
        _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T obj)
    {
        _data[key.Name] = obj;
    }    
    public T Get<T>(Key<T> key)
    {
        return (T)_data[key.Name];
    }
    public class Key<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
    }
}
```

This works quite well:

```
var d = new JsonDictionary();
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Foo, 42);
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Bar, 3.14);
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Vec, new List<double> { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 });
Assert.Equal(42, d.Get(JsonDictionary.Foo));
Assert.Equal(3.14, d.Get(JsonDictionary.Bar));
Assert.Equal(new List<double> { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0 }, d.Get(JsonDictionary.Vec));
```

How can I change the Set/Get API to also accept nullable type ? For instance:

```
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Foo, null);
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Bar, null);
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Vec, null);
```

The following naive attempt did not work for me:

```
public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T? obj)
{
    _data[key.Name] = obj;
}
```

---

Changing the base type as in:

```
public static readonly Key<int?> Foo = new Key<int?> { Name = "FOO" };
public static readonly Key<double?> Bar = new Key<double?> { Name = "BAR" };
public static readonly Key<List<double>?> Vec = new Key<List<double>?> { Name = "VEC" };
```

does work as expected, but requires a bit more typing ... any other solution directly at the `Set` function (with some constraints magic) ?

---

Another solution could be duplicating the code like this:

```
public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T? obj) where T : struct
{
    _data[key.Name] = obj;
}
public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T? obj) where T : class
{
    _data[key.Name] = obj;
}
```

which is also something I do not wish to do. Am I missing something fundamental in this strongly-typed structure ?

Comment: I don't know if I have the right answer here, it's a guess:.  change the base type?  Like:  `Key<int?>`

Comment: To my mind, the best solution is the one given by @devlincarnate, keeping the same base type in the process is better. Your specifying the type in your Keys and in a way you're trying to modify it meanwhile.

Answer (score -1):

The Solution you stated of changing the base Data types to nullable types seems to be the only option. If you try to pass a **null** into a non-nullable data type such as **int** you will receive an error (which your compiler should warn you about) at runtime. **Generics can only perform the functions of the data type it is passed!**

---

```
// will receive an error here v
// passing a null into int
Set(new Key<int> { Name = "FOO" }, null);
public void Set(Key<int> key, int obj)
{
    _data[key.Name] = obj;
}
```

this is essentially what your code was trying to do, the only way I can see it resolved is either by:

1. Fixing the Data type

   ```
   Set<int?>(new Key<int?> { Name = "FOO" }, null);
   public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T obj)
   {
       // Has no issue as you are setting a null to a nullable datatype
       _data[key.Name] = obj;
   }
   ```
2. Discarding the null or reserving a value for null's

   ```
   Set<T>(new Key<int> { Name = "FOO" }, null);
   public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, object obj)
   {
       // check if obj is the same type as T if not sets the name to -1 in the key's type
       // be care full though if you try to pass an int into a float you will also get -1
       _data[key.Name] = (obj is T ? obj : (T)-1);
   }
   ```

Good luck and sorry I couldn't help much